# PHP random DIV with css question

Tags: php, css, random

I tried to use PHP to make DIV random positions. we can look each 100px as a unit, type one small div is 1*1 ,type two small div is 1*2, type three small div is 2*1. All divs only allow show in a big div box 10*6. Here is my code.

```
<?php
function DIV1()
{
    $choose1 = array("0","100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900");
    $choose = array("0","100","200","300","400","500");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    $rand_keys1 = array_rand($choose1, 1);
    echo "<div style=\"position:absolute;top:".$choose[$rand_keys]."px;left:".$choose1[$rand_keys1]."px;width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff0 none;\"></div>";
}
function DIV2()
{
    $choose1 = array("0","100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900");
    $choose = array("0","100","200","300","400");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    $rand_keys1 = array_rand($choose1, 1);
    echo "<div style=\"position:absolute;top:".$choose[$rand_keys]."px;left:".$choose1[$rand_keys1]."px;width:100px;height:200px;background:#f00 none;\"></div>";
}
function DIV3()
{
    $choose1 = array("0","100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800");
    $choose = array("0","100","200","300","400","500");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    $rand_keys1 = array_rand($choose1, 1);
    echo "<div style=\"position:absolute;top:".$choose[$rand_keys]."px;left:".$choose1[$rand_keys1]."px;width:200px;height:100px;background:#00f none;\"></div>";
}
echo '<div style="width:1000px;height:600px;">';

$sizes = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i ++) $sizes[] = DIV1($row);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) $sizes[] = DIV2($row);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) $sizes[] = DIV3($row);
shuffle($sizes);

for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i ++) echo $sizes[$i];
echo '</div>';
?>
```

I still have some css questions. in my code, I make `postion:absolute` and `top` `left` setting, but some divs will `overlapping`. how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle of this.

Comment: @ibu, this is php code, can it run in jsfiddle?

Comment: YEs you can create the a fiddle of the output.

Comment: @Ibu, excuse me in where to put php code in `http://jsfiddle.net/`? paste in html code part is not work...

Comment: what i mean is, run your code in the browser, then take the output and paste in in here or jsfiddle,

Comment: @Ibu, OK, jsfiddle.net/HeukL/ this is one of the random possition. How to make the random div do not `overlapping`? I mean you can see the last bottom of the result line, first 2 blu divs are overlapping, and the last red div's top half part is covered by the top blue div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You should use "return" instead of "echo" in the end line of 3 div functions so that array sizes can have any effect

**2)** Your problem is not standard, it is a little bit mathematical challenge, you must do "remembering" of positions and shuffling by hand

**3)** can this below code be your solution ? ( [test here](http://jalija.com/jalija/various/testDivs10x6.php) )

```
<?php
function divHtml($dtype, $x, $y) //$dtype: (1)=1x1yellow, (2)=1x2, (3)=2x1, (4)=1x1white
{  $ww =($dtype ==3) ?'200px':'100px';    $hh =($dtype==2)?'200px':'100px'; $bgcols =array('#ff0', '#f00', '#00f', '#fff');
   $xx =($x*100) .'px';                   $yy =($y*100) .'px';              $bgc    =$bgcols[$dtype-1];
   return "<div style='position:absolute; width:$ww;height:$hh; left:$xx;top:$yy; background:$bgc;'> $dtype </div>";
}
$divs =array(); //real divs array (html inside)
$cells =array(); //logical filled/notFilled (0/1) array
for ($i=0; $i<60; $i++) $cells[$i] =0; 

function reserve($dtype, $x, $y)
{  global $cells, $divs;      if ($y*10+$x >59 ||($cells[$y*10+$x])) return false;
   switch ($dtype)
   {  case 2: if ($y ==5 || $cells[$y*10+$x] ||$cells[($y+1)*10+$x]) return false;  $cells[($y+1)*10+$x] =1; break;
      case 3: if ($x ==9 || $cells[$y*10+$x] ||$cells[$y*10+$x+1])   return false;  $cells[$y*10+$x+1] =1;   break;
   }
   $cells[$y*10+$x] =1;      $divs[] =divHtml($dtype, $x, $y);       return true;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) while (!reserve(2, rand(0,9), rand(0,5))) ; //adding 10 blocks of type2 (20cellsTotal)
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)  while (!reserve(3, rand(0,9), rand(0,5))) ; //adding  5 blocks of type3 (10cellsTotal)
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i ++) while (!reserve(1, rand(0,9), rand(0,5))) ; //adding 15 blocks of type1 (15cellsTotal)
for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i ++) if (!$cells[$i]) reserve(4, $i%10, floor($i/10)) ; //filling rest 15 cells with type4
               //^go through all cells, but filling only 15

echo '<div style="position:absolute; width:1000px; height:600px;">';
   foreach ($divs as $single) echo $single;
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Great code. thanks a lot. one more question. how do i control the the numbers? if I need `1*1` 15 pcs, `1*2` 10 pcs, `2*1` 5 pcs. the rest are blank blocks. may be also should `definition` another type `1*1`, `background white`.

Comment: aha... it was intentional boundaries of for loops... yes, new type is clearest solution, type 4... color #fff ... so just few changes, i will edit above code. (it is already on the link)